# How can I find $f'(2x)$ given that $xf(x)-yf(y)=(x-y)f(x+y)$?

Tags: derivatives, functional-equations

it might seem a little bit elementary. $f$ is defined on $\Bbb R$ and it is differantiable. and is not equal to zero.

if $xf(x)-yf(y)=(x-y)f(x+y)$ then find what is $f'(2x)$ equal to?. $(f'(x),2f'(x),xf'(x),4f'(x)$ or $8f'(x)?)$

from that equation

$\dfrac {f\left( x+y\right) -f\left( y\right) } {x}=\dfrac {f\left( x+y\right) -f\left( x\right) } {y}$

How to continue?

Comment: You have to be clear what you mean by $f'(2x)$. Do mean $\frac{d}{dx} ( f(2x))$ or do you mean $(\frac{d}{du} f(u)) |_{u = 2x}$. In other words, do you mean to substitute $2x$ first and then take the derivative, or to take the derivative first and then substitute $2x$?

Comment: @CarlMummert I think the notation is quite standard and means $\frac d{dx}(f(2x))$. In fact the notation with $\frac d{dx}$ is more misleading.

Comment: @Mohsen Shahriari: but then by the chain rule we would have $f'(2x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(2x) = g(2x)\cdot 2$ where $g(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x)$. In particular, $f(x) = x$ satisfies the functional equation $xf(x) - yf(y) = (x+y)(f(x) - f(y))$. For that $f$, we would have $f'(2x) = \frac{d}{dx} 2x = 2$ under the convention you state, and $f'(x)$ would be $1$. But several answers below (including yours) claim that the answer is $f'(x) = f'(2x)$.

Comment: I typed the functional equation from the problem incorrectly; it should be $xf(x) - yf(y) = (x-y)f(x+y)$. Still $f(x) = x$ satisfies that, and if $f(x) = x$ then $f'(2x)$ ought to be $2$ under the convention you mentioned, which is also the one I am familiar with. @MohsenShahriari

Comment: Oh! My bad! I just copied the wrong one! I meant that the standard interpretation of $f^\prime(2x)$ is $\frac{d}{d(2x)}f(2x)$ which is equivalent to your other definition. It's exactly the things like $d(2x)$ that makes this notation misleading. In fact the notation $\frac d{dx}$ is bad enough since one might want to change the variable to $t$ for example. The need of a notation for derivative without addressing the variable makes $f'$ a better choice. Sorry again for my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious that every function of the form $f(x)=ax+b$ satisfies the equation:
$$xf(x)-yf(y)=(x-y)f(x+y)\tag0\label0$$
It can be shown that those are the only solutions indeed. To show that, let $a=f(1)-f(0)$ and $b=f(0)$, and define $g(x)=f(x)-ax-b$. It's easy to see that by \eqref{0}, $g$ satisfies
$$xg(x)-yg(y)=(x-y)g(x+y)\tag1\label1$$
and we have $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=0$. Letting $x=1$ and $y=-1$ in \eqref{1} we get $g(-1)=0$. Now, letting $y=1$ and $y=-1$ in \eqref{1}, we respectively get:
$$xg(x)=(x-1)g(x+1)\tag2\label2$$
$$xg(x)=(x+1)g(x-1)\tag3\label3$$
Substituting $x+1$ for $x$ in \eqref{3} we have:
$$(x+2)g(x)=(x+1)g(x+1)\tag4\label4$$
Subtracting \eqref{4} and \eqref{2} we get $2g(x)=2g(x+1)$ and thus $g(x)=g(x+1)$. Hence by \eqref{4} we have $(x+2)g(x)=(x+1)g(x)$ and therefore $g$ is the constant zero function. So $f(x)=ax+b$ and $f$ is differentiable and for every $x$, $f^\prime(x)=a$ which yields $f^\prime(2x)=f^\prime(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

The Identity function satisfies problem conditions and you sure that one of these 5 solutions are correct so the only possible one is $f'(2x)=f'(x)$ :) this is not a proof but answer your question if it is correct problem.

Comment: Lmaooo... Using the way the problem is stated to close in, I approve

Answer (score 2):

One can easily show that if $0\neq x\neq y\neq0$,
$$\frac{f(x+y)-f(y)}x=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}y.$$
(The first equality is a straightforward application of the functional equation and you get the rest for free by symmetry.) Letting $y\to0$, this implies $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=f'(x)$. The left hand side is differentiable with respect to $x$, so the right hand side is too and thus
$$f''(x)=\frac{xf'(x)-[f(x)-f(0)]}{x^2}=0$$
for all $x\neq0$. From this we find that $f'$ is constant except perhaps at zero, and so $f(x)=ax+b$ for all $x\neq0$. Since $f$ is continuous this extends to $x=0$ and hence $f'(x)=a=f'(2x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: More straightforward than my solution, good job! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

This is a tempting thought, not necessarily correct though!

The fact that

$\dfrac {f\left( x+y\right) -f\left( y\right) } {x}=\dfrac {f\left( x+y\right) -f\left( x\right) } {y}$

Is tempting me to apply the limit as $y$ approaches zero for both sides and end with:

$\dfrac {f\left( x\right) -f\left( 0\right) } {x}=f'(x)$

Now you have a clear relationship between the function and its derivative and can be solved as a differential equation. Alternatively, you may want to expand the function in terms of Taylor's.

The above expression is a bit scary, what would $f(0)$ be? Not sure, but this is just a thought.

Comment: Nice approach. To finish off, you could note that
$$-\frac{f(0)}{x^2}=\frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{x^2}=\left(\frac{f(x)}x\right)'$$
and integrate to get
$$\frac{f(x)}x=\frac{f(0)}x+c$$
from which the result follows.

Comment: @Jason, I appreciate the comment and the help.